# Inconsistent Integration involving DiracDelta at boundaries

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm working on integrals involving `DiracDelta` functions at the boundary of the integrals. I'm confused by the output *Mathematica* v10.1.0 gives me in this case:

```
f[x_] := DiracDelta[x] + Exp[-x];

Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
(* 2 - HeavisideTheta[0] *)

Limit[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, b}], b -> ∞]
(* 2 *)

Limit[Integrate[f[x], {x, a, ∞}], a -> 0]
(* 1 *)
```

I understand the first case, where it basically allows me to pick my favorite definition and choose whether I want to include the `DiracDelta` in the integration. However, in the second line (where I evaluate a limit involving the other boundary) *Mathematica* seems to be sure that the boundary has to be included. Lastly, when I let the left integration boundary go to zero *Mathematica* correctly concludes that the `DiracDelta` should not be included, which is of course only correct if we approach `a=0` from above, but this is consistent with the documentation of `Limit`.

My question is why *Mathematica* gives different results for the first two examples and how I can ensure that the `DiracDelta` is always included at the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for what's happening with your second example, but to answer your second question, you can ensure `DiracDelta` is included by integrating over a larger interval then taking a limit.

```
Limit[Integrate[f[x], {x, -ε, ∞}, Assumptions -> 0 < ε < 1/10^10], ε -> 0]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I can break the calculations down, but I cannot really explain the first one.

---

This seems wrong:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x] + Exp[-x], {x, 0, b}]
(*  ConditionalExpression[-Cosh[b] + 2 HeavisideTheta[b] + Sinh[b], b ∈ Reals]  *)
```

Its limit is `2`.  The `ConditionalExpression` suggests that `Integrate` is using assumptions to make choices.  Let's help it out below.

---

This seems right, and equivalent to the first result, `2 - HeavisideTheta[0]`, if `Heaviside[0]` is equal to `1/2`, which it sometimes is:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> b > 0]
(*  1 - E^-b + HeavisideTheta[0]  *)
```

Its limit as `b -> Infinity` is `1 + HeavisideTheta[0]`.

---

This seems right, too:

```
Limit[Integrate[DiracDelta[x] + Exp[-x], {x, a, ∞}], a -> 0, Direction -> 1]
(*  2  *)
```

Since for all `a` (`a < 0`), the integral of the `DiracDelta` part is `1`, we do not get the `HeavisideTheta` in the answer.

Comment: (at) Michael E2: (at least) in Version 8 things are even stranger:  In[168]:= Integrate[DiracDelta[x] + Exp[-x], {x, 0, b},  Assumptions -> b > 0]
Out[168]= 1 - E^-b + HeavisideTheta[0] (*in agreement with your result*)
but now:
In[169]:= Limit[%, b -> \[Infinity]]
Out[169]= 2, miraculously HeavisideTheta[0] has been replaced by the vaule 1.